# I recently installed tor and it cant seem to connect to tor network

Tags: configuration

So I've been to several questions on this regarding some issues with people being inable to connect to the Tor network, yet I am still inable to connect.

After downloading the bundle I click 'Start Tor Browser' which brings me to the 'Tor Network Settings' window. There are two options. I always click the first which loads until it says 'Please wait while we establish a connect to the Tor Network', but it never finishes, ever.

The second option on the 'Tor Network Settings' is to complicated for me to work through on myself as I am not very experience with that type of stuff.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have a read of [I installed Tor but it's not working](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DoesntWork) on the FAQ. It's possible your ISP is blocking your connection, in which case you'll need to follow the instructions on the [Bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en) page.